# Bhakti Parampara saints from South Indian states

Tags: history, philosophy, saint

I am familiar with some of the Bhakti Parampara Poet-saints from Western and Northen part of India and their works. Some of them are -:

**Saint Dyaneshwar** - commentary on Shree Bhagavad Gita (Dyneshwari, Bhavarthdeepika)

**Saint Tukaram** - Abhanga , Kirtan (community-oriented group singing and dancing form of Bhakti)

**Saint Eknath** - Eknathi Bhagvat.

**Saint Namdev** - Abhangas , Bhajans.

**Saint Muktabai** - Preachings to Saint Changdev.

**Saint Ramdas**- Shri Manāche Shloka, advises to mind about  ethical behaviour and love for God.

**Saint Tulsidas** - Shree Ramacharta Manas.

**Saint Meerabai**- Bajan.

**Saint Kabir-**  Kabir -Dohe.

These Saints are Representing **Bhakti Parampara Or Bhakti Tradiation.**

But I don't know much  about  Similar Bhakti Parampara Saints from **South India region i.e., Namely from the States Kerala , Karnataka , Tamil Nadu , Andhra Pradesh**

**So I want to know more about some of the Saints who are associated with Bhakti Parampara or Bhakti Tradiation. Preferably from 12th century to 16th Century and about their literary works.**

Note - You can give answer state wise also.

Comment: Opinion based + too broad

Comment: There have been so many hundreds of saints from South India (Tamil Nadu, Karnataka, Kerala and Andhra Pradesh). So maybe this question is too broad. You can post a separate question about Azhvars if you want to know about them, though I think that has already been asked. Then there are the Nayanmars, Madhvacharya, Vyasaraya and the Dasa Koota, Ramanujacharya and his disciples, Vallabhacharya, Adi Shankara, Guruvayurappan's devotees, the several music composers who lived through 1400s to 1900s. Though the answer given below has some of them.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about them. but tried to gave some details.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar What is a criteria to be called as saint> THat can change from person to person and this question is too broad too

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Still it's a open ended list question and fall under too broad

Comment: @Surya Thanks for pointing out. I have actually missed the brodness of this question & simply instead of thinking  of seprate states , considered south as a whole region when asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must have skipped some of the great saint in my answer, I seriously apologies for that.

**Adi Shankara**
His works in Sanskrit discuss the unity of the ātman and Nirguna Brahman "brahman without attributes". He wrote copious commentaries on the Vedic canon (Brahma Sutras, Principal Upanishads and Bhagavad Gita) in support of his thesis. His works elaborate on ideas found in the Upanishads. Shankara's publications criticised the ritually-oriented Mīmāṃsā school of Hinduism. He also explained the key difference between Hinduism and Buddhism, stating that Hinduism asserts "Atman (Soul, Self) exists", while Buddhism asserts that there is "no Soul, no Self".

Shankara travelled across the Indian subcontinent to propagate his philosophy through discourses and debates with other thinkers. He established the importance of monastic life as sanctioned in the Upanishads and Brahma Sutra, in a time when the Mīmāṃsā school established strict ritualism and ridiculed monasticism.

**Saint Ramanuja (1060-1118)**
His philosophical foundations for devotionalism were influential to the Bhakti movement.

**Madhvacharya**
As a teenager, he became a Sanyasin, also known as Purna Prajña and Ananda Tīrtha. A Hindu philosopher and the chief proponent of the Dvaita (dualism) school of Vedanta

**Raghavendra Swami**
was a renowned Madhwa saint, philosopher and proponent of Dvaita philosophy established by Sri Madhvacharya. He is worshiped as a Guru

**Alvar saints from South India**
Tamil poet-saints of South India who espoused bhakti (devotion) to the Hindu god Vishnu or his avatar Krishna in their songs of longing, ecstasy and service. They are venerated especially in Vaishnavism, which regards Vishnu or Krishna as the Supreme Being. find more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars)

**Bodhidharma 5th or 6th century**
[Reference link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhidharma)

Comment: I think I have given enough information. You would feel proud if you read about the first saint in the list. you will be proud to be a HINDU.

Comment: Bodhidharma was Buddhist monk. He is not a Hindu saint.  The very first line from the reference link says that. Name is Madhvacharya.  I corrected it.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar There were Bhaktas whose devotion flowed out as music for the common people as well... prominent among them were Thyagayya, Annamacharya, Purandaradasa, Siriyalu, Kannappa, Ramadasu including  many more unsung commoners.